Why the recent trend to not indicate deadlines anymore in reviewer invitation letters?
Over the last half year or so I have realised that very many letters that invite me to review papers for journals (all Springer journals, but there are also others) do not communicate a deadline anymore. In many instances (Springer) at least the deadline is indicated when I click the given link in the email before I agree to review, but in some cases I see the deadline only after I accept the review, or no explicit deadline is given at all, it just says "at your earliest convenience" (which of course means never if things with deadline are prioritised).
I'm quite sure that say five years ago it wasn't like that and a deadline was indicated in pretty much all invitation letters. I wonder whether there is a reason for this trend, and what it is.
I am mightily annoyed by this, because for me an indication what speed is expected is essential. I reject review requests that don't give me enough time as a matter of principle (a journal that gives me less than three weeks communicates in this way that they don't want a quality review, and then I won't play with them). I now reject all those requests where I don't see an explicit deadline before I have to decide whether I accept the review as well, but still, does anybody have an idea why they would do such a stupid thing? (If they want to avoid that their requests are declined because the given deadline is off-putting, they get it totally wrong in my case. Or do they seriously want to communicate that there's no deadline at all and if I do this after six months they are still fine??)
Of course another possibility is that this has only happened in a very small handful of journals but just those that ask me, and everyone else (in places different from statistics where I am) have no idea what I'm talking about? Please also tell me whether you experience the same thing.

'[D]oes anybody have an idea why they would do such a stupid thing?' Maybe pick one of the offensive journals and ask someone on its editorial staff?

Many journals (Nature, Springer, Elsevier, …) that I review for always give me deadlines (specific dates or number of days).

Are these relatively-new journals?

@Allure Some yes some no.

@Aruralreader I have asked once, but the person I asked said they hadn't made that decision, the default invitation letter had been changed at a higher level, and only through my question that person had actually become aware of it. Chances are it's not so easy to find the people who are actually responsible for this.

Did they just change editorial management systems?

@Allure Yes, but of course I'd expect that there are reasons if specific things are changed. (Particularly if in my view it was better before and is worse now.)

My guess would be "Too many review invites are being declined. We did a survey/used our imagination and found that the deadlines we communicated are putting people off. Therefore we stopped communicating deadlines up front and just tell reviewers after they've already accepted. We learned this strategy in our Used Car Salesman Marketing course."

Are you speaking primarily of statistics journals? This might be field related.

And, are these journals primarily print, or online?

@Buffy Are there primarily print journals left?

@Buffy Yeah, mainly statistics journals, but occasionally others such as computer science, philosophy. Occasionally old journals that were primarily print in the past. Of course it may be field related - I'm also interested in whether others observe the same thing, but positive votes for the question suggest I'm not alone.

@BryanKrause I was wondering if you may be right. Optimally somebody has some knowledge to confirm this.

It is difficult to say, but here is my anecdotal experience as a mathematician.
In brief, I have a fairly negative opinion of the commercial academic publishing industry. I'll spare you the rant, but the result is that as a referee, my sense of obligation is to the editors, to the author, and to the mathematics research community as a whole -- and not to the publisher.
These "reviewer invitation letters" are generally pro forma, and I'm not sure how closely they actually track the expectations of the editors. If I have any questions or concerns about expectations, then I will ask the editor who initiated the referee request. This often includes telling them how long I expect before I can finish, and asking if that is okay or if they would prefer to ask someone else.
So, I would recommend asking someone on the editorial board (i.e. a researcher in your field, not an employee of the publisher) before you reject any request on principle.

I agree with much of what you say, but I don't see how this (even indirectly) answers the question.  Can you clarify?

@Kimball I don't know the answer to OP's actual question. OP says in a comment that the change was made by higher-ups at the publisher, and I'm trying to argue that this isn't indicative of anything of much importance. For example, if OP gets assigned a "deadline" after accepting a review request, I don't believe they should consider themselves bound to honor it.

@academic Your comment is implied by the first sentence of your third paragraph, but it could stand to be made clearer.

The cynic in me says it is because academics were ignoring the deadlines anyway, so perhaps the editors figured that the marginal effect of adding a stated deadline was nil.

This is improbable, because shorter deadlines lead to faster reviews. https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/jep.28.3.169

@Allure: How dare you let actual scientific research interfere with my gut-level cynicism!  ; )

This is not an answer. A comment at best.

@Allure: I hope you don't trust a single study, at a single journal, in a single discipline, enough to say that "shorter deadlines LEAD TO faster reviews". This is just one data point.

In fact my own policy is to do reviews strictly according to "first come first serve" disregarding deadlines, and a tighter deadline will not pressurise me into doing a faster review. However at the point when I make the decision to do the review, the deadline is important, because I'll say yes if this is about realistic, given my "policy". I know that if the deadline is four weeks and I do it in six, it'll still be OK, Not so sure if the deadline is 10 days. I feel I need to know what the journal expects, by and large (and sure, they will not expect that everybody does it in time).

@Allure That Study does not seem applicable. It only compares different kinds of deadlines. Unless everyone ignores deadlines, shorter deadlines must lead to faster reviews. It does show lower acceptance of the invitation for the shorter deadlines and the actual review times aren’t all that different with many… missing the deadline.

@StephanKolassa yes, but it's still something, and some data ought to still be better than no data.

@MisterMiyagi yes but this answer says academics were ignoring the deadlines anyway. If they were, then presumably one would not get the results in the study.

@Allure The plots of the study does show that 50%-75% ignore the deadline unless paid. Unless taking this answer absolutely literally ("every academic ignores the deadline") that data supports the message ("significant/most academics ignore the deadline").

@MisterMiyagi Yet the 4-week deadline is better for all time periods considered. It clearly has an impact, so it can't be "ignored", even by the 50-75% of reviewers that are late.

In a different industry, the solution would have been "let us add a .cal file for the deadline to our e-mails, so that the reviewers can add the deadline to their calendar with a single click". But the oligopolistic journals have no incentives to improve their user experience.

@Allure The fundamental problem with that study is it does not cover the case we're directly interested in: when no deadline is specified. There's an effect when there's unknowns, people tend to assume the worst.

This has received a few "not an answer" flags. I'm going to rule that it is an answer -- certainly it should not be a comment, as it does not seek clarification or suggest improvements -- and this does state an answer ("because everyone ignores the deadlines anyway") along with a rationale (personal experience in academia). While we would generally discourage writing idle speculation as an answer, the other answers seem equally speculative. Further, we're not likely to get a response from an editor who made the decision to phase out deadlines, so speculation may be the best we can do here.

This answer is very strange. There IS a deadline. It just wasn't stated in the invitation letter and the reviewwer learns it later.

Based on the comments I'd guess that this is because they just changed editorial management systems (e.g., new version of old software) and the new EMS has not been configured in full.
If this guess is correct, then if you decline citing this as a reason, after some time they'll eventually fix their system.

Some EMS don't even let you add a reason for declining, these days.

So you think it's not done on purpose? If you'rer right, I have done my bit already improving the situation... But as it is more than one publisher around the same time, I doubt it.
